# Installing libc6:amd64 on arm64 removes all system packages

Tags: 18.04, amazon-ec2, qemu, glibc, arm64

I'm trying to install `libc6:amd64` on an ARM64 ubuntu machine following [this guide](https://sites.google.com/junsun.net/how-to-run-cuttlefish/home#h.p_6BPPx9SJi9Lu)

As per the instructions there I added the following to my `sources.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Running `apt install libc6:amd64` after this shows a list of packages that will be removed, containing almost every essential system package on the machine. It also asks me to enter "Yes, do as I say" to confirm the changes.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong because confirming the changes in apt would lead to my system completely breaking.

How can I install `libc6:amd64` on an ARM64 machine running Ubuntu?

(The machine is an AWS `a1.metal` instance)

Comment: How is this question related to qemu?

Comment: @nevilad The `qeumu-user-static` package is how Debian enables packages of an architecture to run on machines with a different one